# Send another fetch in Nuxt after both initial fetch and mounted has completed

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

In my Nuxt page I am fetching resources and I expect to receive a `resourceId` in the response.

I also have an `<Ad>` component that gets called several times inside the page template, but the number of instances is unknown.

Each `Ad` receives a `section` and an `adId` prop, based on which they all dispatch a Vuex action which will push these values into an array.

Then, I construct an object from these array items.

My problem is as follows: I need to send a request using `fetchAds`, where I need to pass **both** the object constructed from the array created using the `Ad` components, and the `resourceId` I receive from the fetch in the page.

How can I fetch the ads making sure that both all the `Ad` components are mounted and committed their actions, thus making it possible to construct the object, **and** the result from the fetch in the view has completed, thus making sure the `resourceId` is already available?

I thought of handling it inside the `mounted` hook in the page, but then I can't be sure the `fetch` has completed.

Comment: Why don't you make your calls sequentials into the `mounted()` hook? Like `await first(); await second(); await third()`? That way, you could wait for it to be completed 100%.

Comment: @kissu I'm using Nuxt's built-in fetch mechanism to make use of loading, SSR, and so on. I can't move the initial fetches outside of the fetch hooks.

Comment: You can probably watch `$fetchState.pending` and call the latest action when this one is set to `false`.